# responsive rollover text on top of an image

Tags: html, css

I've put some text on top of an image inside a container div, in a responsive layout. I'd now like to create a "rollover" effect where on mouse over the text gets a transparent green background-color covering the entire div / image. Hence the image looks a bit green.

See http://www.advocatedesign.co.uk/

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant code.  Additionally, have you tried anything to figure this out on your own? Seeing an attempt is always preferable over a "I'd like to do this...any help is appreciated". Lastly, we like the code and a JSFiddle over a link to keep questions relevant (in case the domain no longer exists in the future).

Comment: So do you want the text to have a green background coloring? And do you want the whole image to glow a green?

Comment: and you want us to do this for you??? please show some effort which you have done!!!

Comment: Yup been trying out lots of things for a couple of hours now. It took an afternoon just to get some text ontop of an image. What is JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need another div that you can use as the "overlay" layer.

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/24NyT/1/)**

(In the future, please include a JSFiddle within your question with the relevant code as it helps everyone who is helping you)

HTML

```
<div class="case_study">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <a href="small-woods.html">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Small Woods case study">
        <p>Small Woods</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.case_study{
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
.case_study:hover .overlay{
    background-color:green;
    opacity: .3;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Genius. Brilliant. Thank you so much. I'm new to a lot of this (I've never heard of JSFiddle and I don't know how to get the html and css in those little grey boxes on this site, so thanks for sticking with me and not giving me a hard time. Is there a way to give you some points or reputation or what ever they are called?

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here:

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening here: .case_study:hover .overlay is this the same as writing .case_study a:hover .overlay? I've just tried this and it doesn't work. Your code works I just don't understand how? So on hover over the .case_study div the .overlay div appears? I've checked this websites help page, but it doesn't appear to say how I get the code to go in a grey box with mono-space font.

Comment: @user2991837 It's not quite the same, .case_study:hover will fire when you hover over any of it's children. .case_study a:hover .overlay won't work because .overlay isn't a child of that anchor tag.

Comment: I've played around with your code, putting the overlay div inside the action, so that the overlay is clickable. Works fine, but I don't understand why the overlay div is on top of the image, but behind the white text? See http://jsfiddle.net/Xnsnj/ thanks

Comment: They are both using position: absolute. Which means that you would need to tell them what order they should be layered in. Giving the "overlay" div a z-index remedies the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Xnsnj/3/

Comment: Thanks ever so much. I've set the top:0 and left:0 on the overlay div so that I don't have to use z-index. I can simply order the HTML so that the text on top comes last in the HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/Xnsnj/5/

Answer (score 0):

Please comment on this answer because I'm not sure exactly what you want...
but are you looking for the hover selector?: http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_hover.asp

Set the class to `hover` and stick the desired background-color in there:

```
P:hover
{ 
background-color:green;
}
```